# Getting TypeError: news.map is not a function. What do I miss?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios, fetch

I'm creating a React news app and I don't know why I'm getting this error **"TypeError: news.map is not a function"** when trying to fetch and map the data.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import "./App.scss"
import axios from "axios"
import Article from "./Components/Article/Article"

function App() {

  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

  const apiURL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=287364824682742902893";

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(apiURL)

        setNews(response.data) 
        console.log(response.data)
    }

  return (
    <div className="App">

          {news.map(articles => (
            <Article title={articles.title} />
          ))} 

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### console.log(response.data)

[image: response.data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

response.data you get is an object, it hasn't map method (I visited the link from your code to see it)

suppose you should write setNews(response.data.someProperty) instead, where someProperty is the array in the object

upd: setNews(response.data.articles)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking it was maybe because it was an object, but I don't fully understand what I should change in my code?

Comment: need to see your response.data to answer correctly :)

in short - this line setNews(response.data).
You shall provide setNews with a valid array

Comment: console.log(response.data)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Peza.png

Answer (score 2):

You need to type: `setNews(response.data.articles)`

And later:

```
<div className="App">
        {news.map(({ author, title }, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <div>{author}</div>
                <div>{title}</div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
```